# How to customize the CSS in Angular material 7 drag and drop while dragging, drag preview and drag placeholder?

Tags: angular, html, drag-and-drop, angular-material, angular7

I have found some basic examples of how to use `.cdk-drag-preview` and `.cdk-drag-placeholder` classes and they seem to do the job when there are no nested elements.

Basically, I have a list of actions and each action is represented in a complex `mat-card` format. That portion is actually done as another component but for the sake of this example, I will make it as basic as I possibly can.

My example is similar to this structure:

```
<style>
    .my_action { border: 2px solid red; }
</style>

<div class="drop_area" cdkDropList>
    <div *ngFor="let action of actions"
        (cdkDragStarted)="dragStart($event, action)"
        (cdkDragMoved)="dragMoved($event, action)"
        (cdkDragEnded)="dragEnded($event, action)" cdkDrag>

        <mat-card class="my_action">
            {{ action.name }}
        </mat-card>

    </div>
</div>
```

In angular component

```
dragStart(e, action) { 
    // initialize start X coord
    this.startX = 0;

    // initialize start Y coord
    this.startY = 0;
}

dragMoved(e, action) {
    // record new position
    this.endX = e.pointerPosition.x;
    this.endY = e.pointerPosition.y;

    // logic to set startX and startY
    // TRYING TO CHANGE CARD BORDER COLOR IF this.endX - this.startX > some number
}
```

I want to be able to do the following:

- While dragging a card to the left change its border color to blue, and green when dragging right
- Change border color accordingly for drag placeholder.

The issue of using `.cdk-drag-preview` and `.cdk-drag-placeholder` seems to apply to the draggable `div` (parent of `mat-card`); whereas, I am trying to change its child's border color.

Thanks in advance :)

**ADDENDUM**

My most important challenge is to change the border color in the drag-placeholder.
I am trying to change placeholder's border color and left margin to indicate the user the action has moved to left or right, representing different levels within the list.

Comment: did you try this selector ?  .cdk-drag-preview mat-card, .cdk-drag-placeholder mat-card {}

Comment: @onik I have tried that but it does not work. I feel like when you are dragging a card, material makes a different copy structure for the preview and I cannot seem to connect to that element to change its CSS dynamically

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would something like below accomplish your goal?

Initialize `nativeElement` x and y

```
dragStart(e, action) {
    const rect = e.source.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();

    // initialize start X coord
    this.startX = rect.x;
    // initialize start Y coord
    this.startY = rect.y;
  }
```

Compare X offset and use `rendere2` to set style on `nativeElement`

```
dragMoved(e, action) {
    // record new position
    this.currentX = e.event.clientX;
    this.currentY = e.event.clientY;
    // logic to set startX and startY
    // TRYING TO CHANGE CARD BORDER COLOR IF this.endX - this.startX > some number
    if(this.startX < this.currentX){
      this._renderer.setStyle(e.source.element.nativeElement, 'border-style', 'solid');
      this._renderer.setStyle(e.source.element.nativeElement, 'border-color', 'green');
    }
    else if (this.startX > this.currentX){
      this._renderer.setStyle(e.source.element.nativeElement, 'border-style', 'solid');
      this._renderer.setStyle(e.source.element.nativeElement, 'border-color', 'blue');
    }
  }
```

**Revision:**

To change color while dragging do the following.

Get reference to `#cdkDropList` in the view.

```
@ViewChild('cdkDropList') _dropList:any;
```

Set index in `*ngFor`

```
*ngFor="let action of actions; let i = index"
```

Pass index to function

```
(cdkDragMoved)="dragMoved($event, action, i)"
```

Receive index and reach into the children of the `cdkDropList` to set the style.

```
dragMoved(e, action, i) {
    // record new position
    this.currentX = e.event.clientX;
    this.currentY = e.event.clientY;
    // logic to set startX and startY
    // TRYING TO CHANGE CARD BORDER COLOR IF this.endX - this.startX > some number
    if(this.startX < this.currentX){
      this._renderer.setStyle(this._dropList.nativeElement.children[i], 'border-style', 'solid');
      this._renderer.setStyle(this._dropList.nativeElement.children[i], 'border-color', 'green');
    }
    else if (this.startX > this.currentX){
      this._renderer.setStyle(this._dropList.nativeElement.children[i], 'border-style', 'solid');
       this._renderer.setStyle(this._dropList.nativeElement.children[i], 'border-color', 'blue');
    }
  }
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hdskvc?embed=1&file=app/cdk-drag-drop-overview-example.ts

Comment: The problem with this is that it changes the color when you finish dropping the card.
I am trying to change the color while holding it / dragging it

Comment: see revised stackblitz and answer.

Comment: thanks, this is getting closer. Let me take a closer look once I get to work ;) +1 for effort for sure

Comment: I am accepting this answer, since using #cdkDropList and Renderer2 gave me enough to do my task

Answer (score 1):

When a cdkDrag element is picked up, it will create a preview element visible while dragging.
This will be a clone of the original element.
The cloned element will remove its id attribute and will add the class .cdk-drag-preview.

Use cdkDragMoved with caution, because this event will fire for every pixel that the user has dragged.

```
<div cdkDropList class="example-list">
    <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let action of actions" cdkDrag 
        (cdkDragStarted)="dragStart($event)"
        (cdkDragMoved)="dragMoved($event)">
        {{ action.name }}
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
export class CustomComponent {
    cloned: any;

    actions = [
        { name: "one" },
        { name: "two" },
        { name: "three" }
    ];

    constructor(private _renderer: Renderer2) { }

    dragStart(event) {
        this.cloned = document.getElementsByClassName("cdk-drag-preview")[0];
    }

    dragMoved(event) {
        this._renderer.removeClass(this.cloned, "red");
        this._renderer.removeClass(this.cloned, "green");

        const distance: { x: number, y: number } = event.distance;
        this._renderer.addClass(this.cloned, (distance.x > 0) ? "green" : "red");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it something like this:

```
<div class="drop_area" cdkDropList>
<div *ngFor="let action of actions;let i = index;"
    (cdkDragStarted)="dragStart($event, action)"
    (cdkDragMoved)="dragMoved($event, action, i)"
    (cdkDragEnded)="dragEnded($event, action)" cdkDrag>

    <mat-card class="my_action{{i}}">
        {{ action.name }}
    </mat-card>

</div>
```

```
dragMoved(e, action, index: number) {
    // record new position
    this.endX = e.pointerPosition.x;
    this.endY = e.pointerPosition.y;

    // login to set startX and startY
    // TRYING TO CHANGE CARD BORDER COLOR IF this.endX - this.startX > some number

   document.getElementsByClassName('my_action'+index)[0].style.borderColor='blue';
}
```

Comment: I will look into this, I think I have tried something like this. But my most important challenge is to change the border color in the drag-placeholder

Comment: You see, I am trying to change placeholder's border color and left margin to indicate the user the action has moved to left or right, representing different levels within the list